# Java RMI issue in eclipse

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, network-programming, rmi

I am getting this error and I tried every possible thing but I can't resolve the issue please help to resolve this issue.

I am using Eclipse indigo IDE.

started `rmiregistry` from `cmd`.

```
Exception:
    java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RMISIntf
    java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RMISIntf
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:419)
```

...................

Answer (score 0):

The Registry doesn't have the class named in the `ClassNotFoundException` on its CLASSPATH. The simplest solution to the and several other RMI issues is to start the Registry in the server JVM, with `LocateRegistry.createRegistry().`

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply . but it still giving me the same error .my server and client both are in the same machine . i'm using eclipse IDE . please help me to resolve the issue

Comment: @user2082252 Is it really throwing you a `ServerException` wrapping a `ClassNotFoundException` from the `bind()/rebind()` method if you start the Registry via `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()`?

Comment: Yes i'm getting the same exception